How do you estimate distance between two place fields based on compression rule?

What is the most intuitive way to understand compression rule ? and What can be inferred about the distance from the compression rule?

--> This is my understanding:
During navigation, the firing rate of a place cell peaks at the center of the place field which is anchored at trough of a given theta cycle. Meanwhile, spike activities of place cells corresponding to the last visited place precesses to early phase of the the theta cycle, while the cells corresponding to the next immediate place field precess towards the center from the later phase.
While the order of these spike sequences predicts upcoming location, compression rule governs the time-lag (time distance) between spikes of two place cells belonging to same place field region. Because one theta cycle can only fit so many neuronal spikes, place cells with larger place field will have to have their neuronal spikes spread out, increasing the temporal distance between their spike. Compression rule infers that larger time-lags between spikes correspond to larger distance travelled or time travelled for a given place field.
Is this an accurate understanding?
a. Is it the time-lag recording between two place cells belonging to the same assembly/place field?
b. What happens if an animal walks slowly? The no. of theta cycles required by the place cell assembly would increase. Does compression rule allow us to deduce time taken to travel for when speed is slowed down through the same temporal-lag metrics?

"The distance between adjacent place field peaks of two neurons could be estimated from the temporal relationship of the corresponding neuronal spikes at two different time scales : real-scale time and theta-scale time " - How?

-->
Real-scale time is the time between two peak spike rates at the troughs as measured by the experimenter. (let's say that the speed is constant during the whole navigation)
Theta-scale time is total time where spikes from the assemblies of place cell corresponding to that place field were active??
I know that phase precession gives info on distance travelled within a place field (trough being the centre) but that distance is still not absolute since it depends on the size of the place field which is arbitrary. I guess with compression rule, we can infer how large the place fields are relative to each other? That would still mean we would need absolute size information on one place field right?
References:
Compression Rule : Temporal Encoding of Place Sequences by Hippocampal Cell Assemblies 
"The ratios between real-time and theta time scale representation of distances (“compression”) increased with the length of the represented distance (Figure 2C), suggesting that the temporal coordination of neuronal discharges at the theta-scale improved as the animal approached the predicted place."
Brain rhythms and neural syntax
The temporal relationships of these predictively activated neurons are governed by a “compression rule”: within the θ cycle, the spike timing sequence of neurons predicts the upcoming sequence of locations in the path of the rat, with larger time lags representing proportionally larger distances or travel times.
